# IE 11 Javascript wants unneeded ')'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax-error, internet-explorer-11

I' have a strange behaviour in my IE 11 on a website... I get a console error on this snippet

```
function loadBasket (updated = false, buttonID = -1) {
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'post', 
    url: azr_TemplateDir+'/ajax/page-basket.ajax.php', 
    success: function (data) { 
        $('.ajax-basket').html(data);
        azrBinds();
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        if(updated && buttonID >= 0) {
            var button = $('div[data-buttonid="'+buttonID+'"]');
            button.addClass('updated');
        }
    },
    error : function(jqxhr,textStatus,error){
        console.log(textStatus + ", " + error);
    }
});
}
```

My IE 11 says that it wants a ')' at Line 1 column 30, but that would be right after the equal sign... Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Edge doesn't show this error.

Does anybody had a similar problem? I'd be happy for every help

Thanks

Comment: IE11 doesn't support default parameters - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: How I which that people would stop using an obsolete browser that is dead even to microsoft themself.

Comment: @Endless Why you think it's dead? https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0

Comment: @Justinas  it doesn't get any more updates but security patches, it's time to switch to edge or any other browser. Sure, it's still in use but that is cuz ppl don't know how to update/switch browsers

Comment: according to [statcounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-partially-combined-market-share/desktop/worldwide/#monthly-201508-201706) it's 7.71% as opposite to netmarkets 13.71%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because IE 11 doesn't support defaults.

```
function loadBasket (updated, buttonID) {

  updated = typeof updated === "undefined" ? false : updated;
  buttonID = typeof buttonID === "undefined" ? -1 : buttonID;
  // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support default parameters.

Use this structure instead:

```
function loadBasket (updated, buttonID) {
    updated = typeof updated !== 'undefined' ? updated : false;
    buttonID = typeof buttonID !== 'undefined' ? buttonID : -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support default parameters in functions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

You'll have to write default values by hand, like :

```
function(a){
    a = typeof a==="undefined" ? 6 : a;

}
```

Comment: hopefully a is not 0 :)

Comment: or false :) better check for type